# Is the order of data in the sequential partition memory table returned by ploadText consistent with that in the CSV file?

Tags: csv, dolphindb

I load the data from a CSV file into the dolphindb database. When using loadText, the disk is not full. If a file size exceeds 100GB and is loaded by the function “ploadText” which return an in-memory table of sequential partitions. I am worried that the sorting is messed up. Do I need to do re-sort again?

Answer (score 0):

The order after importing by function "[ploadText](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/p/ploadText.html)" is the same as the CSV file. If the data in the CSV file is incremented by the Time column, you can use the [isMonotonicIncreasing()](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/i/isMonotonicIncreasing.html) function to verify it after importing.